# Converting uint24 and unsigned char to 32bit signed int with python struct

Tags: python, struct

I'm trying to convert 24bit unsigned int and a unsigned char to 32bit signed int as follows
0x62a40a**cc** => 0x**cc**62a40a as signed int

```
uint24=struct.unpack('>I', '\0' + self.read(3))[0]
byte=struct.unpack('!B', self.read(1))[0]
print hex(uint24+(byte<<24)) #0xcc62a40a
print struct.pack(">i",uint24+(byte<<24)) #error
```

the error i get is:

> struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647

Comment: Use `>I` instead of `>i`.

Comment: I want signed int as result

Comment: @Koten: The result of `struct.pack` is a string, so it does not make a whole lot of sense to talk about it being either signed or unsigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) module to do the conversion for you:

```
sint32 = ctypes.c_int(uint24 + (byte << 24)).value
```

This will give you a 32-bit signed integer.